# tikz nodes are offset to the right

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I'm converting a diagram I previously made into `tikz` using nodes and  `positioning`. I defined all the nodes relatively (e.g. `right = of <other node>`), but for some reason the last two rows of nodes are offset to the right. My suspicion is that I set the locations of the wrong nodes relatively, but I'm not sure what would fix it.

Below is my current-code base:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, positioning}
\tikzstyle{red-rounded-rectangle} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30, align=center]
\tikzstyle{green-rounded-rectangle} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30, align=center]
\tikzstyle{blue-rounded-rectangle} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30, align=center]

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.5cm]
\node (scotus) [green-rounded-rectangle, text width = 10cm]{
{\Huge \textbf{The Supreme Court}}
};
\node (state) [green-rounded-rectangle, right = of scotus, text width=4cm]{
{\large \textbf{State Supreme Court}}\\
Highest Law of the State
};
\node (12-appeals) [red-rounded-rectangle, below = of scotus,, text width = 4cm]{
{\large \textbf{12 Federal Courts of Appeals}}\\
Hears Appeals from lower courts. Geographically distributed.
};
\node (94-district) [blue-rounded-rectangle, below = of 12-appeals,, text width=4cm]{
{\large \textbf{94 District Courts}}\\
Hears cases and deals verdicts. \textit{Judge Judy} except federal.
};
\node (court-appeals) [red-rounded-rectangle, below = of scotus, right = of 12-appeals,, text width=4cm]{
{\large \textbf{Court of Appeals for the Federal Circuit}}\\
Hears special federal appeals. (e.g. patents)
};
\node (legis-courts) [blue-rounded-rectangle, below= of court-appeals, right = of 94-district, text width = 4cm]{
{\large \textbf{Legislative Courts}}\\
Weaker Courts created by Congress. (E.g. \textit{Court of Military Appeals})
};
\node (state-appeals) [red-rounded-rectangle, below  = of  state, right = of court-appeals, text width = 4cm]{
{\large \textbf{State Court of Appeals}}\\
Hears Appeals from Trials on a Case-By-Case basis.
};
\node (trial-court) [blue-rounded-rectangle, below = of state-appeals, right = of legis-courts, text width=4cm]{
{\large \textbf{Trial Court}}\\
Your typical \textit{Judge Judy} case. Hears either criminal or civil cases, and deals verdicts.
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Below is the output I'm getting:
[image]

And below is the desired output I'm converting from:
[image]

NOTE: The arrows from the original pic is a feature I'm planning on adding after the offset is resolved.

Comment: When you say at the start of the second row `below=of <node>`, it will align the `north` anchor of the new node with the `south` anchor of the one above it. This would be fine if you just wanted one node here, but you are trying to fit two. Off-topic: `\tikzstyle` is deprecated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, `below` means 'align my `north` anchor with the `south` anchor of this other node'. And that is what Ti*k*Z does. But you want the nodes to be shifted left, because you want to fit two under one. Easiest is to put the final node of the second row down before the two earlier ones, I think.

For example,

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows.meta, positioning}
\tikzset{
  red-rounded-rectangle/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30, align=center},
  green-rounded-rectangle/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30, align=center},
  blue-rounded-rectangle/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30, align=center},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.5cm, >/.tip=Latex, thick]
  \node (scotus) [green-rounded-rectangle, text width = 10cm]{
    {\Huge \textbf{The Supreme Court}}
  };
  \node (state) [green-rounded-rectangle, right = of scotus, text width=4cm]{
    {\large \textbf{State Supreme Court}}\\
    Highest Law of the State
  };
  \node (state-appeals) [red-rounded-rectangle, below  = of  state, text width = 4cm]{
    {\large \textbf{State Court of Appeals}}\\
    Hears Appeals from Trials on a Case-By-Case basis.
  };
  \node (12-appeals) [red-rounded-rectangle, left=of state-appeals -| scotus, text width = 4cm] {
    {\large \textbf{12 Federal Courts of Appeals}}\\
    Hears Appeals from lower courts. Geographically distributed.
  };
  \node (94-district) [blue-rounded-rectangle, below = of 12-appeals,, text width=4cm]{
    {\large \textbf{94 District Courts}}\\
    Hears cases and deals verdicts. \textit{Judge Judy} except federal.
  };
  \node (court-appeals) [red-rounded-rectangle, right = of scotus |- state-appeals, text width=4cm]{
    {\large \textbf{Court of Appeals for the Federal Circuit}}\\
    Hears special federal appeals. (e.g. patents)
  };
  \node (legis-courts) [blue-rounded-rectangle, below= of court-appeals, text width = 4cm]{
    {\large \textbf{Legislative Courts}}\\
    Weaker Courts created by Congress. (E.g. \textit{Court of Military Appeals})
  };
  \node (trial-court) [blue-rounded-rectangle, below = of state-appeals,  text width=4cm]{
    {\large \textbf{Trial Court}}\\
    Your typical \textit{Judge Judy} case. Hears either criminal or civil cases, and deals verdicts.
  };
  \draw [->] (trial-court) edge (state-appeals) (state-appeals) edge (state) (state) edge (scotus) (legis-courts) edge (court-appeals) (court-appeals) edge (scotus.south -| court-appeals) (94-district) edge (12-appeals) (12-appeals) -- (12-appeals |- scotus.south) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I've also updated your code to avoid the deprecated use of `arrows` and `\tikzstyle`. Note that `text centered` makes no sense if you have `align=center` and that `minimum width=3cm` does nothing, as `text width` is always larger.

[image: aligned courts]

Comment: For the `12-appeals` node, you specified the direction `left=of state-appeals -| scotus`. What does the `-|` operator mean?

Comment: @BrianLee Align with the y coordinate of the default anchor `state-appeals` and the x coordinate of the default anchor of `scotus`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly different answer using a dummy node and some minimum heights added to make the boxes look more uniform.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, positioning}
\tikzset{red-rounded-rectangle/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum
width=3cm, minimum height=2.2cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30,
align=center,text width = 4.5cm},green-rounded-rectangle/.style={rectangle, rounded corners,
minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30,
align=center,minimum height=1.5cm},blue-rounded-rectangle/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners,
minimum width=3cm, minimum height=2cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30,
align=center,text width = 4.5cm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.5cm,font=\sf]
\node (scotus) [green-rounded-rectangle, text width = 10cm]{
{\Huge \textbf{The Supreme Court}}
};
\node (state) [green-rounded-rectangle, right = of scotus]{
{\large \textbf{State Supreme Court}}\\
Highest Law of the State
};
\node[below =1.5cm of scotus,xshift=0.4cm](dummy){};
\node (12-appeals) [red-rounded-rectangle,left=of dummy]{
{\large \textbf{12 Federal Courts of Appeals}}\\
Hears Appeals from lower courts. Geographically distributed.
};
\node (94-district) [blue-rounded-rectangle, below = of 12-appeals,]{
{\large \textbf{94 District Courts}}\\
Hears cases and deals verdicts. \textit{Judge Judy} except federal.
};
\node (court-appeals) [red-rounded-rectangle, below = of scotus, right = of 12-appeals]{
{\large \textbf{Court of Appeals for the Federal Circuit}}\\
Hears special federal appeals. (e.g. patents)
};
\node (legis-courts) [blue-rounded-rectangle, below= of court-appeals, right = of 94-district]{
{\large \textbf{Legislative Courts}}\\
Weaker Courts created by Congress. (E.g. \textit{Court of Military Appeals})
};
\node (state-appeals) [red-rounded-rectangle, below  = of  state, right = of court-appeals]{
{\large \textbf{State Court of Appeals}}\\
Hears Appeals from Trials on a Case-By-Case basis.
};
\node (trial-court) [blue-rounded-rectangle, below = of state-appeals, right = of legis-courts, text width=4.5cm]{
{\large \textbf{Trial Court}}\\
Your typical \textit{Judge Judy} case. Hears either criminal or civil cases, and deals verdicts.
};
\draw[thick,-latex] (trial-court)--(state-appeals);
\draw[thick,-latex] (legis-courts)--(court-appeals);
\draw[thick,-latex] (94-district)--(12-appeals);
\draw[thick,-latex] (state-appeals)--(state);
\draw[thick,-latex] (court-appeals)--(court-appeals|-scotus.south);
\draw[thick,-latex] (12-appeals)--(12-appeals|-scotus.south);
\draw[thick,-latex] (state)--(scotus);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

some how similar to other answer, however, nodes style is determined different and width of "the supreme court" is calculated, because image is draw from bottom to top.  consequently the nodes are not misplaced:

```
%\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, positioning}

\begin{document}
%\begin{figure}[htb]
%\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 6mm and 4mm,
   box/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, thick,
                 draw=#1!70!gray, fill=#1!30,
                 text width=4cm, minimum height=1cm, align=flush center,
                 font=\sffamily\linespread{.8}\selectfont}
                        ]
% first row, on the bottom
\node (94-district)     [box=blue]
   {\textbf{94 District Courts}\\
    \scriptsize
    Hears cases and deals verdicts. \textit{Judge Judy} except federal.};
\node (legis-courts)    [box=blue, right=of 94-district]
   {\textbf{Legislative Courts}\\
    \scriptsize
    Weaker Courts created by Congress. (E.g. \textit{Court of Military Appeals})};
\node (trial-court)     [box=blue, below right=0mm and 4mm of legis-courts.north east]
   {\textbf{Trial Court}\\
    \scriptsize
    Your typical \textit{Judge Judy} case. Hears either criminal or civil cases, and deals verdicts.};
% second row
\node (12-appeals)      [box=red, above=of 94-district]
   {\textbf{12 Federal Courts of Appeals}\\
    \scriptsize
    Hears Appeals from lower courts. Geographically distributed.};
\node (court-appeals)   [box=red, above=of legis-courts]
   {\textbf{Court of Appeals for the Federal Circuit}\\
    \scriptsize
    Hears special federal appeals. (e.g. patents)};
\node (state-appeals)   [box=red, above=of trial-court]
   {\textbf{State Court of\\ Appeals}\\
    \scriptsize
    Hears Appeals from Trials on a Case-By-Case basis.};
% third row
% firs calculate spreme court node width
\path   let \p1 = ($(12-appeals.west)-(court-appeals.east)$),
            \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)} in
        node (scotus)
            [box=green, font=\sffamily\Huge\bfseries,
             text width=\n1-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep},
             above=of $(12-appeals.north)!0.5!(court-appeals.north)$]
            {The Supreme Court};
\node (state)       [box=green, right = of scotus]
   {\large\textbf{State Supreme Court}\\
    \scriptsize
    Highest Law of the State};
\draw [-Stealth, thick]
    (trial-court)   edge (state-appeals)
    (state-appeals) edge (state)
    (state)         edge (scotus)
    (legis-courts)  edge (court-appeals)
    (court-appeals) edge (scotus.south -| court-appeals)
    (94-district)   edge (12-appeals)
    (12-appeals)     to  (12-appeals |- scotus.south) ;

\end{tikzpicture}
%\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]